# boost asio async_read documentation

Tags: c++, boost-asio

There is inconsistency between [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp) example and `async_read` [manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html). According to the manual `async_read` [handler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html) expects 2 arguments: error code and how many bytes were transferred, but in the example the handler accepts only error code. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting type from `boost::bind` still meets the requirements of [ReadHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html).  [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bind/bind.html)'s documentation states that extra arguments are silently ignored.

For example, in the internals of Boost.Asio, the ReadHandler call chain may look something like:

```
handler( error, bytes_transferred ) 
`-- binder::operator()( error, bytes_transferred )
    `-- bound_function( error )
```

For a better illustration and explanation of `bind`, consider reading [this](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/bind-illustrated.html) blog entry.  One of its illustration specifically shows the case of surplus arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's ok, to call bind object operator() with more than N args.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template<typename T>
void call(const T& f)
{
   f(1, 2, 3, 4);
}

void f(int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }

int main()
{
   call(boost::bind(&f, 1));
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/1MrPTQ$2

```
template<class R, class F, class L> class bind_t
{
public:

    typedef bind_t this_type;

    bind_t(F f, L const & l): f_(f), l_(l) {}

#define BOOST_BIND_RETURN return
#include <boost/bind/bind_template.hpp>
#undef BOOST_BIND_RETURN

};

result_type operator()()
{
    list0 a;
    BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
}

result_type operator()() const
{
    list0 a;
    BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
}

template<class A1> result_type operator()(A1 & a1)
{
    list1<A1 &> a(a1);
    BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
}

template<class A1> result_type operator()(A1 & a1) const
{
    list1<A1 &> a(a1);
    BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
}

template<class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5, class A6, class A7, class A8, class A9> result_type operator()(A1 const & a1, A2 const & a2, A3 const & a3, A4 const & a4, A5 const & a5, A6 const & a6, A7 const & a7, A8 const & a8, A9 const & a9)
{
    list9<A1 const &, A2 const &, A3 const &, A4 const &, A5 const &, A6 const &, A7 const &, A8 const &, A9 const &> a(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9);
    BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
}

template<class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5, class A6, class A7, class A8, class A9> result_type operator()(A1 const & a1, A2 const & a2, A3 const & a3, A4 const & a4, A5 const & a5, A6 const & a6, A7 const & a7, A8 const & a8, A9 const & a9) const
{
    list9<A1 const &, A2 const &, A3 const &, A4 const &, A5 const &, A6 const &, A7 const &, A8 const &, A9 const &> a(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9);
    BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
}

template<class R, class F, class A1>
    _bi::bind_t<R, F, typename _bi::list_av_1<A1>::type>
    BOOST_BIND(F f, A1 a1)
{
    typedef typename _bi::list_av_1<A1>::type list_type;
    return _bi::bind_t<R, F, list_type> (f, list_type(a1));
}
```

And for example realisation operator() of boost::bi::list1

```
template<class R, class F, class A> R operator()(type<R>, F & f, A & a, long)
{
    return unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_]);
}
```

call f with one argument, regardless of number of elements really doned.